# Committing specific parts of a file in Git

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I commit only part of a file in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/how-can-i-commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

I have made several changes to a file and have also added it to the git index. While committing the file I realized that I actually have changes which should go in separate commits with other files.

Is there a way to commit only specific parts of this file in Git?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use:

```
git add -i
```

to add files interactively. This will allow you to stage only the parts of the files you wish to commit. [More info here](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/version-control-with-git-git-add.html), and [a decent tutorial here](http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/14/interactive-adding.html).

Comment: You can also run 'git add --patch' to skip directly to selecting hunks.

Answer (score 10):

Use `git gui`, it can add only specific parts of a file to the index. I think you can do it using `git add -i` (interactive mode) too, but I've never used it.

Comment: For me "git gui" is easier to use than "git add --interactive".

Comment: Just tried --interactive and got completely lost. git gui did it for me, nice and easy! :)