# Commit specific lines of a file to git

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I commit only part of a file in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/how-can-i-commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

How do I commit a few specific line ranges from a file to git? while ignoring some other line changes in the same file.

Comment: SourceTree makes it much easier and less confusing

Comment: SourceTree doesn't let me pick lines only hunks. Often I can't split a hunk down to the lines I want

Comment: This questions asks for specific lines, I would like to provide them as numbers. Linked question is different that this one.

Comment: For most cases `git add --patch` might suffice, but for control over *precisely* which lines are added, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78110952/5783745)'s what worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 638, accepted):

Try `git add -p` -- it will interactively let you add, skip, or split diff hunks.

Comment: When I do this, git chooses what constitutes a hunk of change. For instance, I changed a file in three places, but it only gives me two chunks as options to commit: one containing the first two changes, and one for the third change. Is there a way to specify actual line numbers, as the OP asked?

Comment: @NathanLong `git add -p` lets you break up the hunk into smaller hunks. See the 'a' option. If that doesn't work then maybe the 'e' option will. See the "Interactive mode" section of http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html

Comment: @ThomasW - I think you mean 's' not 'a'

Comment: @asgeo1 yes, you're right, I meant 's'.

Comment: I found a good tutorial for anyone getting started with `git add -p` or using the 'e' option for the first time: http://johnkary.net/blog/git-add-p-the-most-powerful-git-feature-youre-not-using-yet/

Comment: To clarify the above, once a hunk is displayed, if you press 's', it will break it into smaller hunks.

Comment: To get help/ explenation of the choices press `?` then enter as your first command.

Comment: IIRC, does not work on files that are not added yet.

Comment: In that case you need `-N`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27321496/322020

Comment: Is there a mode analogous to git-rebase, i.e. to just open whole diff in editor, and mark the lines I want to commit with, say, `a`?

Comment: It looks like there's a limit to the granularity of the hunks ('Sorry, cannot split this hunk'). Does anyone know of a way to split a hunk that contains multiple lines? I have a print statement sandwiched between meaningful changes that I'd like to omit.

Comment: Edit to my comment above: you can type 'e' to open up an editor and modify the hunk manually.

No idea why this is a separate interface. Seems like you should be able to just select line-by-line instead of git deciding for you what an atomic change is.

Comment: And after open editor with option 'e', you just need to comment (using #) to not adding this lines.

Comment: Instead of using the interactive selector and then opening the editor with option 'e', one can also directly use the editor with `git add -e`

Answer (score 39):

Use [`git add -i`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) to stage the lines then commit as normal, or use [git-cola](http://git-cola.github.io/) until you get used to the command line.

[image: Staging lines of a file]

Comment: Or `git gui`, as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085202/4669135) of the duplicate question.