# Multiple commits on single file

Tags: git, commit

I have a File with 10 logical changes I want to commit the file for each line that is per line per commit, to have a complete understanding of the line added or changed to the other Engineer

Comment: I just got the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309156/commit-specific-lines-of-a-file-to-git

Comment: If thats the case, Why not add a comment over that line in your code so that whenever a new developer look at that code, (s)he easily understands the code.