# Is there a best way for analysis unstable function in c source file in git repo?

Tags: git

I maintain some c source code files. I get a task to find out what function is unstable. Unstable means functions be modified frequently. Actually I want get the statistic data to point out which function was modified how much times and each time by who.
First I try to use git blame to get the information, but i am failed. Then I read many answer here, still can not find the best way.
So i want ask you is there any tool or method can help me to do the job?
Thanks very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456846/13126651

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225120/2915738) help? [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310999/2915738) shows possible solution with `log`  command. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks to @AsifKamranMalick `s information, I done the job.

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this statistic?

Comment: @Rudi move stable code into ROM, and unstable code into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I done the job with following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat [function_list_file] | while read line
do
    echo $line
    git log -L :$line:path/subpath/file.c | grep commit -c # Get numbers of commit
    git log -L :$line:path/subpath/file.c | grep commit -2 # Get commit information
done
```

**[function_list_file]** is a file contain function name list, as:

```
funciton_1
funciton_2
funciton_3
funciton_4
funciton_5
funciton_6
funciton_7
funciton_8
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function be moved from file a.c to file b.c at commit_x, we can use

```
git log -L :function:path/subpath/b.c
```

to get commits at HEAD of the latest commit. But we can not use

```
git log -L :function:path/subpath/a.c
```

to get commit at HEAD of the latest commit.

After resetting HEAD before commit_x,

```
git log -L :function:path/subpath/a.c
```

works.

Now I solved this problem by the following steps. I can find commits related to a function in all files.

```
git log -p | grep function -3 > run.log
cat run.log | grep "void function(" > run2.log
cat run2.log | grep @@ -c
```