# Apply a commit chunk by chunk

Tags: git, diff, commit, git-diff, git-commit

When I add a file to staging, I can

```
$ git add my_file -p
```

And select the chunks I want to stage.

Is there a way to merge/cherry-pick a commit and apply its diff chunk by chunk?

Thanks

Comment: also have a look at vim fugitive. It's interactive hunk selection rocks

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not aware of a direct way to do this but here's an indirect way.

`git cherry-pick -n <commit>`

Cherry pick the commit but tell git not to commit it (`-n`).  The changes should now be in your working copy so you can do

`git checkout -p`

This will iterate over each chunk and ask if you want to discard it, say yes to any chunks you *don't* want and no to chunks you want to keep.

Comment: That's definitely a solution. Cheers!

Comment: just a little precision:
After the git cherry-pick -n <commit>,
we need to to a git reset -p (and take what we want off from staging)