# How to ignore changes to a file when committing with Git?

Tags: git, branch

I did search for the solution, yet I believe my situation is a bit different than those I read about.

I am working on a particular branch and made a mistake, having edited a file in a way that is unrelated to the theme of the branch, and now want these changes to not make it into the commit. I do not want to lose these changes, as I will try to commit them on another branch later, one way or another.

I tried `git rm --cached` but then I see status `deleted` in my `git status` - will the file be *removed* from the repository? I don't want that - I want it to stay unchanged from whatever it is in previous commit on my working branch.

Comment: Just don't stage some of the files. This is a completely normal and trivial use of Git. You'll be doing this more often than not with each and every commit. Are you using `git add .` or `git commit -a`? Stop using that, and start using `git add -p` *every single time*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not stage the changes, they will not be part of the commit, something like this:

```
git status
# On branch development
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ResearchProposal.tex
```

Here, `ResearchProposal.tex` has changes, but they will not be committed by `git commit`.

If you have two sets of changes *in a single file*, some that you want to commit and some that you don't, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/how-can-i-commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git).

If you've run `git add` on a file that you don't want to commit, you need to `unstage` it:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

like this:

```
$ git add ResearchProposal.tex
$ git status
# On branch development
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   ResearchProposal.tex

$ git reset HEAD ResearchProposal.tex 
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   ResearchProposal.tex

$ git status
# On branch development
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ResearchProposal.tex
```

Comment: The file is listed among changes to be committed. I don't know how it got there, probably because I `add`ed it accidentally earlier, or for another reason. So I guess, now I need to somehow make it appear among "changes not staged for commit", which is what I am after, right?

Comment: `git reset <file>` to unstage the file, or `git reset .` to unstage everything and `git add -p` to selectively stage stuff.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

To make Git track the file again, simply run:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions:

```
git stash
git checkout <another-branch>
git stash apply
git add <one-file>
git commit 
git stash
git checkout <original-branch>
git stash apply
```

Comment: Is there a way `git stash` will only stash one single file? I don't need to stash entire working directory, only one file.

Comment: It appears that @simont's answer is what I needed. Thanks for the alternative :-)

Comment: @amn: in ``git`` you can do one thing multiple ways. Choose whatever suits you better.