# Partial git commit from eclipse (egit)

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Say I have a file with 2 changes. How do I use egit to commit only one of them?

The command line version can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git) question.

Comment: The egit documentation says [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Partial_Staging) - does that work for you?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can also follow "[Git Partial Staging in Eclipse](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/03/git-partial-staging-in-eclipse/)"

> From the staging view, double-click on the file. A compare dialog will appear.
>
> - On the left are your current changes;
> - on the right is the currently staged work.
>
> You can now copy changes from the left to the right, effectively staging parts of your file. In this case I will stage the correction to the method name.

[image: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Screen-Shot-2014-06-02-at-11.11.26-PM.png]

Comment: Huge thankyou! This will save me huge amounts of time.

Comment: Just in case anyone misses out on this (not that I did and wondered for quite some time why it does not work): Press Ctrl+S (or whatever your hotkey is) to save the changes... Saving will not affect your current file you work on, but just the changeset.