# Inline bash script in pre commit hook

Tags: bash, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

---

```
      - id: check-modified-files
        name: Check for Modified Unstaged Files
        entry: bash
        language: system
        args:
        - -c
        - |
            if [ $(git diff Resources/config | wc -l) -ne 0 ];then
              echo "Error: Unstaged files found in the specific folder: ./Resources/config"
                exit 1
            fi
```

Trying to add a pre commit hook which will fail if unstaged files are detected in a specific folder. This is always giving passed even if some files are unstaged. Could you please tell whats the issue here ?

Comment: `git diff Resources/config` could be throwing an error, sending error message to stderr and `git diff Resources/config | wc -l` is returning 0

Comment: Check the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041090/git-warning-for-new-unstaged-files

Comment: Nope, it's not throwing error, have checked it. Could you please tell what's wrong here ? Thanks in avance

Answer (score 0):

from [the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit) -- pre-commit will always *discard* changes to the working directory before executing hooks.  hooks run on what is about to be committed -- not on whatever state the user may have to local files in the working directory.

so your `git diff` will never result in changed files and the hook will always pass.

a slight minor issue -- you probably also want `pass_filenames: false` when writing script hooks that don't operate on files

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit