# Seeing the expected results of a commiting only part of a file in git?

Tags: git, patch

So let's say I've already run [git add -p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git) and I've selected the hunks I'd like to add to the file, and the hunks I would not like to add to the file.  How can I see the resulting file in full based on what is about to be committed without committing it?

I tried using `git diff --staged` as linked above but it only shows me the changes staged for commit, and not the full resulting file that will be committed to my local repository.  Or should I just not worry about that, commit anyway and then [undo the last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should b able to see the file currently cached (staged) with:

```
git show :file
```

[`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) uses [`gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

> `:path` (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax: content recorded in the index at the given path.

Comment: Just for the record, if you don't include the `:` before the filename it doesn't work; but if you do, it does.

Comment: @leeand00 I agree. That is why I mention the special syntax `:path` in the answer: the '`:`' is important.