# Do the unstaged hunks of a file stay in the file in the working directory when I only stage some of the changes in a file for commit?

Tags: git, patch

If I commit [only part of a file in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git), does it keep my other unstaged changes in the file the working directory?  So I can add them to another seprate commit?

Comment: Yes. Try it on a new empty temporary repo, if you need more confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does keep the hunks that are not included in the commit in the working directory; and the changes that aren't included in the commit within the file end up staying the same when you look at the commit.