# git: can't create upstream branch

Tags: git, github, branch, upstream-branch

## The problem

I'm going bananas due to this git (or github?) idiosyncrasy - I've created a new branch, but I can't push it to the upstream repo on github. This is not the first branch I'm pushing on this repo, and everything went smooth so far.

## Walkthrough

I've created a new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b adam/no-push-bugfix
```

Made some changes to a file, [and added some of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git) (this means that some of the changes were not committed):

```
$ git add --patch path/to/some/file
```

Made sure the changes are right:

```
$ git diff --staged
$ git commit -v
$ git status
```

And tried to push:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin adam/no-push-bugfix
$ fatal: adam/whatever-name-bugfix cannot be resolved to branch.
```

**Any idea why is my new branch rejected from upstream?**

Comment: Aside from `/`, are there any strange characters in the real branch name? Does `git branch` show the branch locally?

Comment: Concerning the `/`, do you have a branch on the remote named just `adam`?

Comment: Oddly enough, the branch was created but I was not in it for some reason. Another `git checkout adam/whatever-name-bugfix` solved it. Strange.

Answer (score 6):

I could not find the right explanation for this issue on the Internet. So I am adding this to help other people to understand the problem.

Git branch name is case-sensitive and it is mapped to a file/directory in repository (not always but it is common for a new branches). As result case-difference in git branch name may cause a problem like in your case. In this particular case we see that existing branches are started with "Adam/". It means that there is a folder with name "Adam" exists in .git/refs/heads. When you try to push to a branch with name started with "adam/" it conflicts with exiting folder.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR - checkout the branch again.**

Oddly enough, I seem to have been out of the branch somehow. The `oh-my-zsh` prompt shows that I'm in the branch, but `git branch` shows that I'm not in any branch:

[image]

After `git checkout Adam/no-push-bugfix`, I seem to be in the branch:

[image]

Now everything works well, and I can push the branch to upstream. I'm not sure what's the problem (there's a case difference, for example, between `adam` and `Adam`).