# Commit only part of a file in CVS

Tags: cvs

Analogous to [this question about git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git), when I make changes to a file versioned by a CVS repository, how can I commit only some of the changes?

I can run `cvs diff > patch.diff`, edit the file `patch.diff` then commit the diff, but is there any command in CVS that can do this like the command `git add --patch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there is no way to do this.

Comment: :-( Thanks for the answer anyway.