# How to Add Modified Changes to File Without Adding the Entire File in Git?

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-commit, git-add

I used `git checkout` to pull a file from a certain branch on Git, and made the small modified changes to it. However, I don't know how to add the changes without adding the whole file.. meaning that I am using `git add` to add the file I just modified.. However when I used `git commit`, and then `git show <commit-id>` to see the changes.. every time they rewrite the whole file as insertions, instead of showing insertions, deletions.

Basically how do I add my modification to a file without having to insert the entire file? (I am trying to push a commit to a existing pull request on GitHub and I don't think it's wise to rewrite, and push a entire new file instead of just the small changes)

Please advise

Comment: Have you tried git git add -p?
You can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git

Comment: It should "just work" by adding the file with the changes and committing.  Is it possible the file is being seen as a binary file vs. source code?

Comment: You need to make sure you did not change line endings, as that could cause the entire file to "change".

Comment: You probably use different editor on that file that change its line ending and indention. That's technically make it change all the file.

Comment: @Joe how do I verify how the file is being seen?

Comment: How do I control the line endings in git on VM (Windows)?

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf input` is what I do. I'd be happy to have a git expert correct me.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you so much! This fixed my problem (: