# Trying to git add -p <file_name> but git does nothing

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

I'm trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085162/3512538) in order to apply a big change I've worked on. I did the following:

```
 1. git pull (before I started working)
 2. changed some code
 3. git diff > ~/my_diff
 4. git stash
 5. git pull
 6. git stash pop
```

This failed due to conflicts, so I tried:

```
 7. cp ~/my_diff ./
 8. git add -p ~/my_diff
```

But I get nothing... The file contains a lot of changes, but for some reason it suggests no hunks to patch. What is the problem?

---

This is the exact response from **git**:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with '...'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        my_diff

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
.../trunk $ git add -p my_diff
    No changes.
```

---

Here is the `head -30 ~/my_diff`:

```
diff --git a/trunk/files_transfer_mgmt/inc/files_transfer_mgmt.h b/trunk/files_transfer_mgmt/inc/files_transfer_mgmt.h
index 28907bd..f108931 100644
--- a/trunk/files_transfer_mgmt/inc/files_transfer_mgmt.h
+++ b/trunk/files_transfer_mgmt/inc/files_transfer_mgmt.h
@@ -13,6 +13,7 @@
 #include "iss_api.h"
 #include "rf_termserver.h"
 #include "rf_versions_util.h"
+#include "common_apis.h"

 #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
@@ -23,23 +24,40 @@

 #define DEVICE_SFP             "/dev/sfp"

-#define        SECONDS_TO_USECONDS(seconds)    (seconds * 1000000)
+#define SECONDS_TO_USECONDS(seconds)   (seconds * 1000000)
+
+#define DEFAULT_FTPS_ERR_LOG "FTPS_error_log_tmp.txt"

 #ifdef __cplusplus
         }
 #endif /* __cplusplus */

 void SECURE_StartFileDownloadFromHere(void * data);
+void SECURE_ZT_entry_point(void * data);
 void SECURE_StartGenericFileTransferFromHere(void * data);
 void SECURE_getDownloadStatus(int argc, char *argv[],FILE *fin, FILE *fout,pedro_callback_func_args_t *pedro);
```

so you can see it is a well formed diff file

Answer (score 3):

`git add -p` does not read a file-of-patches.  Instead, it takes a file that is already under Git's source code control, and compares the index version of that file to the work-tree version of that file.  Whatever is different, *that's* what `git add -p` lets you interactively patch into the index.

Hence, instead of what you were doing, you would have had to save every modified file somewhere, switch commits, restore all the modified files into your work-tree, and *then* run `git add -p` (with no arguments at all).  But this is generally quite the wrong way to go—it loses everyone *else*'s changes.

Instead of this sequence, here is what I would recommend, and why:

> 1. `git pull` (before [starting work])

Split this into `git fetch; git merge`, just so you know precisely what `git pull` is doing to you.  (One might say *for you*, but in the case of `git pull`, it tends to do it *to* you instead of *for* you.  My experience with the bad old days of Git 1.5 may be showing here. :-) `git pull` used to break repositories badly in some corner cases.)

I actually use `git merge --ff-only` here just to be doubly sure that nothing odd has occurred.  (I have an alias, `git mff`, that runs `git merge --ff-only`, for short.  Sometimes I use a few other tricks, but that's plenty for now.)

> 2. changed some code

Keep this part. :-)

> 3. `git diff > ~/my_diff`

Don't bother with this.  Instead, run `git add` and `git commit`.  If you made a lot of changes in step 2, you can make a new branch name first:

```
git checkout -b mostly-ready  # or some more suitable name
git add -u         # or `.` or `-a` if you prefer
git status         # check for unexpected new files, or untracked files
                   # make any adjustments you like here
git commit
git checkout -     # go back to previous branch
```

> 4. `git stash`

This is no longer required.  All `git stash` does is make commits that are on *no* branch; and by doing the above, or a simpler `git commit`, you have made a commit that is on some more suitable branch.

> 5. `git pull`

Split this into `git fetch; git merge` or, if you made the commit on the branch itself rather than on a side branch, `git fetch; git rebase`.  (You can run `git pull --rebase` to do the fetch-and-rebase sequence, but again, I think it's better to keep the two steps separate.)

> 6. `git stash pop`

Since you don't have a stash, there will be nothing to pop here.  If you made the commit in place and used `git rebase`, rebase will have the merge conflicts, if there were any, from transporting your commit forward.  Otherwise your commit is on your side branch `mostly-ready`, or whatever you called it, and now you can run:

```
git cherry-pick -n mostly-ready
```

The `-n` tells Git *not* to commit the result.  This gives you a chance to look it over and use `git add -p` if you like.  If there are merge conflicts, the `-n` is redundant as Git won't be able to commit the result anyway.  Note that there's an important caveat: *some* of your changes may already be staged.

#### What *staged* means, precisely

It's important to remember, here, that in Git, there are *three* copies of every file.  Let's take a file named `README.txt` for instance.  The three copies are:

- `HEAD:README.txt` (try `git show HEAD:README.txt`).  This is a *committed version* of the file, specifically the one in the *current* commit (aka `HEAD` aka `@`).

  This copy is frozen into a commit.  Being in a commit, it is permanent (well, as long as the commit exists) and 100% read-only.  It's stored internally in a Git-only, compressed format—sometimes very compressed.  Few if any other programs can deal with it; it's basically a Git-only format, so you have to use `git show` or `git checkout` to get at it.
- `README.txt`.  This is the *work-tree* version.

  This is just an ordinary file.  You can do anything you like with it.  Git does not really care that much about this copy; Git just put it into your work-tree so that you can access it and work on / with it.
- `:0:README.txt`.  This is the *index* version.

  The index, which is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, holds a version that Git *does* care about, but that is in the special, compressed, Git-only format.  This file is ready to go into the *next* commit you will make—but unlike the frozen, read-only, *committed* version, you *can* overwrite the index copy.

  That's what `git add` does: `git add README.txt` overwrites the index version, `:0:README.txt`, with the work-tree version, `README.txt`.  This is when Git tells you that there are *changes staged for commit*.  It's not that `README.txt` has suddenly *appeared* in the staging area: it was there all along.  It's just that now that you copied a modified `README.txt` over top of the old `:0:README.txt`, now the version in the staging area is *different from* the version frozen into the `HEAD` commit.

So, the thing to remember here is that you have to work on your *work-tree* files: you can edit these and so whatever you like.  But once you have done that, you then have to *copy* the work-tree version *over top of* the index version.  Some Git commands, like `git checkout`, start out by making the frozen committed version and index version the same.  Some, like `git cherry-pick`, can change the index version (usually while also changing the work-tree version).  Using `git add` overwrites the index version completely.  Using `git reset`, you can overwrite the staged version with the frozen `HEAD` version:

```
git reset README.txt
```

means *copy `HEAD:README.txt` over top of `:0:README.txt`*, without touching the work-tree `README.txt` at all.

When you do eventually run `git commit`, what this does is really pretty simple: it freezes all the index versions into a new commit.  They're already in the right form, sitting there in the index / staging area.  The files in the work-tree are not important; only the files in the index matter!

#### Two very useful `git diff` forms

Running:

```
git diff --cached
```

compares, for every file, the `HEAD` (frozen) version to the index version, and shows you the difference.  That's *what's different in the commit you're about to make.*

Running:

```
git diff
```

compares the index (ready-to-commit) version of every file to the work-tree version, and shows you the difference.   That's *what's different in the commit you could make, vs what you could `git add`*.

Running:

```
git status
```

runs *both of these diffs* for you, and then shows you the *file names* (only) that are different.  The files that are different between `HEAD` and index are *staged for commit*, and the files that are different between index and work-tree are *not staged for commit*.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, but I now know how to do this for new situations, not how to fix the current...

Comment: I used git apply -3 (staged the ok hunks, and created a swap with the conflicting). Seems easy-ish to work with

Comment: BTW you can also use `--reject` with `git apply`; this is sometimes useful for reducing the amount of remaining work to do.

Comment: I tried it before the -3. The reject notes didn't help me understand how to fix the patch, so I used -3 to see the actual patching done, and that was simpler

Comment: Yes, using -3 usually works better, it's just good to know about both.

Answer (score 0):

To apply your my_diff you should use git command to apply patch as given below,

git apply mydiff

Comment: This option causes merge conflicts and I would like to avoid it. Additionally, I want to patch the file hunk by hunk to make sure I approve all changes

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to "git diff" before pull, just stash. Then pull, "stash pop", and fix conflits. Git does not remove your changes from the stash, so if you fail your conflict fix, you can start again. You should manually empty your stash at the end (only in case of conflicts)

Comment: That doesn't help me. I already did what I did. Besides, the diff was so I could backup in case I collosally f***ed up