# Commit only part of a file in Git using sublime merge

Tags: git, git-commit, sublimemerge

Is there a way to do [Commit only part of a file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git) in Sublime Merge?

Comment: I went to https://www.sublimemerge.com/ and the demo animation (“stage lines”) looks a lot like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SublimeMerge forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-stage-unstage-individual-lines/39547) is clear:

> > Most wanted git feature for me is ability to stage/unstage individual lines.
>
> you can, just select the line and the (un)stage hunk button will change to (un)stage line

[image: Sublime Merge Stage Hunk button]