# How to apply a patch(copy only some lines from experimental to suggestFix branch) from experimental branch(local) onto suggestFix branch(local)?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

So I have 3 branches: `master`, `suggestFix` and `experimental`. `suggestFix` points at the same place as `master` because I want to use `master` as a starting point to create pull request on GitHub. `Experimental` has different commits, and I want to move to `suggestFix` branch only some lines of code from `experimental`.

I'll provide a concrete example. Here's final file on experimental branch:
[image]

And here are master and suggestFix branches:

[image]

I want my suggestFix branch to look like this after I do whatever is needed with git tools:
[image]

I don't care how history looks like as long as I can make a pull request and it will look like I modified master and got from master to `suggestFix` with line insertions(as it usually shows in pull requests on GitHub).

I understand that I will need to review every single line of every single file and either accept or reject edits of lines or how they are also called hunks of code. That's what I want. I use a mix of Atlassian Sourcetree and MINGW64. I managed to start some kind of diff on Sourcetree:
[image]

But I don't understand how to do per-line patch and get to a file that I need(that you can see above on the third picture). Please help, I've been trying to do it for hours.

Here's a GitHub repository with that specific example:

https://github.com/KulaGGin/GitPatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I have 3 branches: master, suggestFix and experimental. suggestFix points at the same place as master because I want to use master as a starting point to create pull request on GitHub. Experimental has different commits, and I want to move to suggestFix branch only some lines of code from experimental.

Answer to this is to switch to suggestFix branch, then run `git merge experimental --squash`. This will squash all the commits from experimental into a single commit and stage them. So unstage all the changes first and then run `git add --patch <filename>` to pick hunks of code you want to commit. [Detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085191/6693304). Or you can more easily do it in a tool with UI like Sourcetree:
[image]

Then you just commit the changes you staged on the suggestFix branch. Then you can remove all unstaged changes with `git reset --hard`.