# Apply and remove a commit frequently

Tags: git

So here is the scenario

When working locally I change up a few files by adding test data. Basically pre-populate some fields etc, to boost productivity whilst working and testing.

Obviously this needs to be undone when I commit and push just the task related changes.

How can I apply and remove this locally easily.

I have created the pre-populate as a commit that I revert, then cherry pick to reapply. However this leaves history of reverts and cherry picked commits.

Is there a a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git

Comment: You could also `git stash` your test data and then apply it when needed.

Comment: I'm personally fond of using [Stacked Git](http://www.procode.org/stgit/) for this sort of thing. I keep my debug code and configuration in a separate patch (or multiple patches) in my stack, so I can pop it off or push it on the stack whenever I need.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use [`git update-index`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) feature. This is particularly efficient when the file in question is not often modified in the repository.

Let's consider that the file which you edit with test data is called `index.asp`. Instead of cherry-picking the modified version of the file, and then reverting it, keep a copy of index.asp in a separate file, either gitignored, or in a directory outside of the repository.

Copy this file over `index.asp` whenever necessary.

Then, to have git consider that this file is not modified:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged index.asp
```

git will not offer anymore to stage the modifications on the file anymore.

Later, whenever you want to restore the original version of the file:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged index.asp
git checkout -- index.asp
```