# Is there a way to make comments in Xcode so that doesn't show in a pull request?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on my team's codebase and taking notes within it to clarify what I don't understand. Obviously I don't want the notes to show up when I make a pull request. Is there a way to type out notes so that it doesn't happen, besides creating a copy of the codebase for note taking purposes? Maybe there's a CocoaPod out there that can do this?

Comment: But adding a cocoapod into Podfile, Podfile.lock will still be exposed to git commit. 
You could write a small script, which will delete all your comments from all .swift files.
And you would run it before commiting. Like if line starts with //CLARIFY: -> then delete the line. And when you commit it, return it back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commit only part of a file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

Comment: The simplest, safest and least time consuming solution is probably to take notes on the side, saving them in a text file outside of the project folder