# Push partial file changes in git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, tfs

I am trying to figure out how to push partial file changes from my local git repo to a tfs git project.

For some background, I have a project that uses an external wsdl. I have a local dev instance of the wsdl on my machine, and the production application will run on a production version of the wsdl hosted on a different server. I have the project in my local git repository pointed to my local dev wsdl, and the production project in tfs pointed to the remotely hosted wsdl.

My issue is that when I push code changes from my local dev repo to the tfs repo, I don’t want my connections to the dev wsdl being pushed with the changes. My end goal is to be able to make code changes, bug fixes, etc, and push those to the tfs repo without changing any of the production configurations.

I may be going about this incorrectly, but figuring out the best way to tackle this is why I’m here. Are there specific procedures developers usually use to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commit only part of a file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I had not seen that yet but I’ll take a look and give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @mkrieger1 this isn’t exactly what I was looking for. I should have been more precise...when I want to move changes to the tfs project, I would first merge them from the dev branch to the prod branch in my local repo. After that, I would push the prod branch to the tfs repo. The merge is where I’m having issues. I found something on “cherry picking” commits, but it doesn’t seem to be a widely recommended practice

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different configuration file between branches, when you perform merge, you would get conflicts. For this scenario, you could check [Merge Strategies](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies).

> You can also use Git attributes to tell Git to use different merge
> strategies for specific files in your project. One very useful option
> is to tell Git to not try to merge specific files when they have
> conflicts, but rather to use your side of the merge over someone
> else’s.
>
> This is helpful if a branch in your project has diverged or is
> specialized, but you want to be able to merge changes back in from it,
> and you want to ignore certain files. Say you have a database settings
> file called `database.xml` that is different in two branches, and you
> want to merge in your other branch without messing up the database
> file. You can set up an attribute like this:
>
> ```
> database.xml merge=ours
> ```
>
> And then define a dummy `ours` merge strategy with:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global merge.ours.driver true
> ```
>
> If you merge in the other branch, instead of having merge conflicts
> with the `database.xml` file, you see something like this:
>
> ```
> $ git merge topic
> Auto-merging database.xml
> Merge made by recursive.
> ```
>
> In this case, `database.xml` stays at whatever version you originally
> had.

`.gitattributes` - is a root level file of your repository that defines the attributes for a subdirectory or subset of files.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here some suggestions maybe you can have a try:

1. Try using **`.gitignore`** for your repository to ignore the files you do not want to push.
2. If the files you want to push is not too many, generally only several files, you can use the [**git add**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) command to add these files as the pushed files.

For example:

```sh
git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3
git commit -m "commit message"
git push
```

In this example, only the files `path/to/file1`, `path/to/file2` and `path/to/file3` will be pushed to remote repository.

3. If there are many changed files you need to push, you can try as the following steps.

- Make sure the local repository has been up to date with the remote repository. If not, use **`git pull`** or **`git fetch`** command to update local repository.
- Copy the local repository to a temporary folder in another directory that outside of the repository directory.
- Do changes of the code in the temporary folder.
- Use some the tools, such as [**Beyond Compare**](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php), to extract the changed files you want to push.
- Copy the extracted files to the local repository to overwrite the original files.
- Commit and push the changed files.