# How can I commit only staged hunks in git?

Tags: git, github

I run these command to commit:

```
git add --all -p
// Then use "y" to stage hunks, and use "n" to not stage hunks
// I want to commit hunks which staged with "y"

git commit -a
// Then commit all
```

But when I check, all of hunks which used "y" and "n" in *git add* committed to branch
How could I just commit just hunks which I selected when using *git add*?

Comment: Don't run git commit with `-a`? You're telling git to stage everything modified and deleted and commit it. Also, you stage hunks, not hulks.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `git commit` instead of `git commit -a`. The `-a` option will stage all new and modified files, basically making your previous staging activity obsolete.

Look here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit
And here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging