# Are replaced files logged or deleted?

Tags: git, github, frontend

With facebook i have a 30 days recycle bin menu. Files are deleted after a period of 30 days.
(With my personal logging i am aware that after connections logged entries can be abused.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding your actual question here, but maybe https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html will help you understand what commits are made of in Git...

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git

Comment: The git `push` command is used to upload **local repository content** (project or files present in your computer) to a **remote repository** (like GitHub).  The changes you make in your local repository will be implemented exactly to your remote repository like GitHub. Whether you have deleted the files or edited a code `git push` will implement same things to your remote repository.

Comment: Prevent abuse is the main concideration with the whole web entries. Not only mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to commit the changes to your GitHub repo that you did in your local machine/computer. You should run following commands (if you have linked your project to GitHub repo):

`git add .`

`git commit -m "type message of your choice"`

`git push`

Enter the credentials & done. Only the lines that you have changed in your script will get updated. That's how git/GitHub works

2. If you only want to Commit only part of a file in Git then [source](https://intellipaat.com/community/3449/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

Case 1: If your file is in the repository, use the following command:

```
git add --patch <filename>
```

Git will begin to break down your file into what it thinks is sensible portions of the file, also called "hunks."

Git will then prompt this question:

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,s,e,?]?
```

Description of each option:

```
y: stage this hunk for the next commit

n: do not stage this hunk for the next commit

q: quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining hunks

a: stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file

d: do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file

g: select a hunk to go to

/: search for a hunk matching the given regex

j: leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk

J: leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk

k: leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk

K: leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk

s: split the current hunk into smaller hunks

e: manually edit the current hunk

?: print hunk help
```

Case 2: If the file is not in the repository yet, run the following command:

```
git add -N <filename>
```

Now, run the following command

```
git add --patch <filename>
```

Tips:

Use the following command to check that you staged the correct changes:

```
git diff --staged
```

To unstage mistakenly added hunks run the following command

```
git reset -p
```

To view your commit while you edit the commit message.

```
git commit -v
```

Comment: Deleted the blockquoted sentence from my above question, it was well placed in your, not from me confirmed, answer. My question posted has been changed to find a start recource entry maybe with git init.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount that has to be changed for developing with github server side
the first steps should be managed with a personal token to search the
possibilties that can be achieved within a personal reachable environment.
Past creating an account within github the frist step should be to add a file
online.

[image]

README.md is a file with a markdown extension that is commonly used. With
my experience some files are not the world. For a homepage as owner in the settings the pages option has to be concidered.

My opinion is that first some informations should be collected written down
or rather typed to the README file.

My proposal for the first steps to research is how to make a folder.
How to move the README file to the created folder.
Not use the pages tab until an additional main.md file is created.

I do not have knowledge about github moderated server side policies.
Until a repeated recognition service, some documentation are hard to find.

I prefer to aim the moderated sense to my work. Therefore i consider
sites like
[Suchmaschinenoptimierung](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Suchmaschinenoptimierung)
to figth the timer tensions that are not ergonomic suited for my workspace.

A main markdown file for server structures is somewhere for server side
integration proposed. A README file is also possible, but do you know why?
I do not.